# Spring datasource configuration is ignored when trying to use H2 file for storage locally

Tags: spring, kotlin, h2, application.properties

I'm trying to create simple spring boot application with some REST API and storage to run locally. I initialized application using [Spring initializer](https://start.spring.io/) now trying to configure database for testing locally so I added these settings in `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/data/my_app_db
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=usr
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2/console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
```

As I understand this should configure my h2 console path and file database path, but in logs I get this output:

```
INFO 22917 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:4bcaeb11-32f9-442d-9e8f-439608ffd960'
```

I can not understand what am I missing. Shouldn't this work and if not why?

Comment: does that file live under src/test/java/resources/application.properties ?

Comment: No it is in `/src/main/resources/application.properties`

Comment: for your tests, try putting it in the src/test folder. you can leave your production src/main application.properties file as is

Comment: Yes but I'm running `Application.kt` from IDEA directly I won't be using h2 console from tests

Comment: ah, now I understand your question. :D